# What does $row stand for in prepared statements (MySQLi)?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm watching a login system guide on Youtube, and recreating it. It's about done, but every time i try to login, it gives me an error:

> "Incorrect Password"

I suspect this has to do with the **$row** that was made in an if statement. But i don't know what **$row** does.

I'll leave some code if someone can see the problem.

```
   <?php
    else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
            if ($pwdCheck == false) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                exit();
            }
            elseif ($pwdCheck == true) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

                header("Location: ../index.php?login=succes");
                exit();
            } ?>
```

Comment: Look at [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). `$row` would be the first row of the results

Comment: *"I suspect this has to do with the $row that was made in an if statement. But i don't know what $row does."* - Then why do you suspect that?  `$row` is an object representing a single row of the query results.  From the description it would appear that the row being returned does not match the password being compared.  You'll want to debug to ensure that you're querying the row you expect to query, that the values are what you expect them to be, etc.  Basically, debug instead of guess.

Comment: I would bet the password column in the database is not the right length OR that the hash process for new passwords was not performed properly. Show us how you store the passwords, including the table definition.

Comment: A [mcve] **must** include input and database samples. See any of the prior questions on password_hash/verify for possible debugging steps.

Comment: Don't post an answer when you want to update your question... edit the initial question instead.

Answer (score 0):

> if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

This tries to fetch a row from the query result. If there is a row to fetch from the results, then that row is assigned to the **$row** variable and the **if** statement is executed. If there is not a row to fetch from the results, then the **if** statement returns **false** and is skipped.

Comment: But then why is it returning false? I'm certain i put the right password in. (btw thanks for answering)

Comment: Not sure. You only posted a portion of the script. And that also was not what you were asking. You asked what the '$row' variable was. You should restructure your question and include the rest of the relevant code sample to reflect what you are trying to achieve.